# Python code execute in lambda to trigger to move file from one s3 bucket to other

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I try to execute the below code in AWS lambda function

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 dest_bucket =  s3.Bucket('keyan-fin-bkt')
 source_bucket = s3.Bucket('keyan-hr-bkt')
 print(dest_bucket)
 print(source_bucket)
 
 for obj in source_bucket.objects: 
  dest_key=obj.key
  s3.object(dest_bucket.name,dest_key).copy_from(copysource = {'Bucket' : obj.bucket_name, 'Key' : obj.key})
```

I am getting this following error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'s3.Bucket.objectsCollectionManager' object is not iterable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    for obj in source_bucket.objects:\n"
  ]
}
```

what is the issue ?

Comment: `source_bucket.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1):

source_bucket.objects has class s3.Bucket.objectsCollectionManager which is not iterable, you should use source_bucket.objects.all() instead.
So your final code should look like:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dest_bucket = s3.Bucket('keyan-fin-bkt')
    source_bucket = s3.Bucket('keyan-hr-bkt')

    for obj in source_bucket.objects.all():
        dest_key = obj.key
        s3.Object(dest_bucket.name, dest_key).copy_from(
            CopySource={'Bucket': obj.bucket_name, 'Key': obj.key}
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse , i created policy only to allow Getobject on my source bucket but using  objects.all()  i am getting access denied  so what privilege to add to overcome this issue

Comment: after executing the above code i am getting the following error  "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied",                         what to do on this issue  i have editied my policy and gave list and read access to my source bucket

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/s3-copyobject-access-denied-5f7a6fe0393e

Comment: @Keyan have you added write permissions into the target bucket policy?

Comment: yes i created    Allow: s3:PutObject to destination bucket